# Import in Babel translation

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

In a module's documentation, it says I should import a component by:

`var LineChart = require("react-chartjs").Line;`

What would be the translation of this be using `import` in Babel? The `.Line` is the confusing part for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Babel module `import`](https://babeljs.io/learn-es2015/#ecmascript-2015-features-modules) equivalent would be:

```
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs';
```

Comment: Perfect, I was trying `import { LineChart } from 'react-chartjs'`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No worries, glad to help out :-)

Comment: It would be good to be clear "In Babel the equivalent is", ES6 does not in any way define how an ES6 module should import a CommonJS module, and this will likely not work when Node implements ES6 modules.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I updated my question as well, thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

You would write

```
import { Line as LineChart } from 'react-chartjs';
```